# Displaying cards inside a responsive container with a grid of 3x3 initially

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I'm trying with **bootstrap** and **django** to list cards inside a **responsive container** which in xl screen displays as a **3x3 grid container**, has a **scrollable overflow**, and *decreases according to device width*. I tried to achieve this at first by *wrapping the cards with a flex container with column-layout*, but that's only a temporary and undesired solution, also *i thought about rearranging cards through javascript upon window-resizing* (but that's not optimal), or ... in other way using other techs like *css-grid* (of which i don't know anything about how it works right now). So, what would be the best approach for this...
Here i leave you guys a model i drew for this ocassion and serves as an explanatory to the main problem.

[image]

**CODE HERE JUST SERVES AS A TOOL FOR BETTER UNDERSTANDING... BUT IT'S NOT CRUCIAL:
i have here one card.... let's say i put 12 instead.**

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="scrolling-wrapper d-flex flex-column flex-wrap  align-items-center">
        
                
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="card-img">
                                <img src="{% static 'library/img/attention.jpg' %}" class="history-img" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, co
                            </h6>
    
    
    
    
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <span class=""><i class="fas fa-eye"></i>4093</span>
                            <span class=""><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>1234</span>
                            <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill px-2">#hello_there</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
            </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    body * {
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
}
.history-img{
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;

}

.scrolling-wrapper{
    max-height: 700px !important;
    flex-wrap: wrap !important;
    
}

.card{
    
    width: 20%;
    height: 200px !important;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="scrolling-wrapper d-flex flex-column flex-wrap  align-items-center">
        
                <div class="card-container">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="card-img">
                                <img src="{% static 'library/img/attention.jpg' %}" class="history-img" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, co
                            </h6>
                        </div>
                   //other cards goes here
                     </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <span class=""><i class="fas fa-eye"></i>4093</span>
                            <span class=""><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>1234</span>
                            <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill px-2">#hello_there</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
            </div>
```

for css:

```
.card-container{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  text-align:center;
  grid-gap: ; // this is for the gap between your cards
}
```

and for responsiveness you can add media queries manipulate the `grid-template-columns`  , the number of arguments define the number of columns.